# Poisson process (find mean) - solution check

Tags: probability, self-study, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Mary receives 22 messages in 5 hours according to a Poisson Process. What is the mean number of messages Mary receives in an hour?

Seems like a simple question, so just to confirm: Mean = 22/5

Isn't it?

Comment: It might be helpful to contemplate under what circumstances your answer might change if "according to a Poisson process" were changed or even omitted altogether.  To what extent does, or should, your assumptions about a phenomenon determine your description of what actually happened?

Comment: @whuber I believe that even if Poisson Process is removed from this question - the answer stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The units on the rate, say $\lambda$, should be messages per hour. First, **do you have the right units?** Trivially, 
$$\frac{22 \text{ messages}}{5 \text{ hours}}=\frac{22}{5} \text{ messages/hour}$$

Next, your $\lambda$ should be the **average number** of messages per hour.  With a little thought on how an *average* is calculated, you should be feeling pretty decent.